# When using git commands in batch script, how to fail on error?

Tags: git, batch-file

Below is the batch script in which I am executing a set of git operations, how I can fail on a git error like on git checkout "Branch already exits"

```

```
REM arg 1 = branch to copy
REM arg 2 = branch in which copy will be merged
set arg1=%1%
set arg2=%2%
echo copying %arg1% to %arg2%
echo "check out as tmp "+%arg1%
set ret = git checkout -b tmp %arg1%
echo %ret%
set ret = git checkout -b tmp %arg1%
echo %ret%
exit 0
REM emitted code for brevity
```

```
output :

```
c:\my-project>c:\bat\git-copy-branch.bat master my-git-branch

c:\my-project>git checkout -b tmp master
fatal: A branch named 'tmp' already exists.

c:\my-project>git checkout -b tmp master
fatal: A branch named 'tmp' already exists.

c:\my-project>git checkout -b tmp master
fatal: A branch named 'tmp' already exists.
```

Comment: I am not sure how you are getting any `GIT` output because the code you are showing never executes `GIT`.  Also your `SET` commands are incorrect.  You need to remove the spaces before and after the `=` symbol.

Comment: @Squashman oops... embarrassed.. that something I was trying.. you are right set cmd `set ret = git checkout.... ` don't do anything... I am correcting.. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
REM arg 1 = branch to copy
REM arg 2 = branch in which copy will be merged
set arg1=%1%
set arg2=%2%
echo copying %arg1% to %arg2%
echo "check out as tmp "+%arg1%
git checkout -b tmp %arg1%
if errorlevel 1 goto Quit
echo Ok
git checkout -b tmp %arg1%
if errorlevel 1 goto Quit
echo Ok
:Quit
```

`:Quit` is a label. `if errorlevel 1` checks if there was any error in previous command; it really checks if errorlevel >= 1.